# % signs on deb package names?

Tags: package-management, deb

I just wanted to create a copy of (/var/cache/apt/)archives directory and clean it to save some space. Noticed **%** signs on certain packages (ex-ffmpeg_6%3a0.8.12-1_amd64.deb). Just wondered what that sign means on a package name. Updated packages?! Just curious to know.

Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%3a` is the URL-encoded form of `:`. Some characters in the file names are not suitable for URLs, and hence are encoded.  Whenever you see `%` in a package file name, you can safely assume it and the next two characters are the URL-encoded form of some character. Try converting at http://www.url-encode-decode.com/, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and enlightening me. Have a good day!